# angularjs: setting focus on a previously-hidden input element inside a directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

[Here is a simplified plunk to illustrate the problem](http://plnkr.co/edit/uLHP5BBYV6TWIA5An82E?p=preview)

I got an angular directive that compiles some html code before visualizing it. In the html, there is an hiden input that becomes visible only if `scope.isEditShown` is `true`:

`<input ng-show='isEditShown' type='text' value='{{content.name}}' class='title_edit'/>`

The input appears when the `scope.titleChange` function is invoked. This function (bound to an ng-dblclick directive) just sets true to `scope.isEditShown` and tries to invoke jQuery's `focus()` method on the input element (previously stored in the scope in the linker function with `scope.input = $("input:text", ae);`:

```
scope.isEditShown = true;
scope.input.focus();
```

In short, I want to visualize a previously-hidden input when something is double-clicked, and give it immediate focus. The immediate focus is needed because the input is hidden when it loses focus (I want the user to immediatly be able to edit the input content. When the user clicks away, the input is hidden).

The problem is that it seems I can't give the focus to the input element programmatically.
After experimenting, I found that when `scope.isEditShown = true;` is executed, the input is not visible yet (= angular js doesn't show it in the DOM), and setting focus with `scope.input.focus();` to a hidden input does nothing. When the input element finally gets shown, it's unfocused.

What is the angular way to do what I want? When can I be sure that my input is shown and when can I call `focus()` on it effectively? NOTE: if I use `scope.$apply()` before giving focus to the input, I will get `$apply already in progress` exception. If I do a safe apply, foucus won't be given. See [the plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/uLHP5BBYV6TWIA5An82E?p=preview).

(ps: I really want to understand, so I'm not gonna use companion libreries that automagically do that for me)

Comment: Can you put your code in a plunk or jsfiddle?

Comment: make a very simple demo with just enough code to represent the issue, try using `$timeout`

Comment: @ganaraj: just edited the answer with a plunkr.

Comment: @charlietfl a demo was provided

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When you make changes to some data-bound variable and you need to wait for the corresponding rendering to happen, you need to use the famous `setTimeout` 0 ( alternately in Angular the `$timeout` service ).

Here is a plunkr that shows how to do this.

http://plnkr.co/edit/N9P7XHzQqJbQsnqNHDLm?p=preview

Comment: This works indeed. Philosopycal question: is it right to rely on timeouts? All the javascript literature I know of is screaming "NO" in my head.

Comment: Javascript is single threaded. Also there is no way of knowing when the rendering phase is done. The only reliable way currently is to use a setTimeout,0 which basically tells javascript that "do this as soon as you are done with everything". Also there are no cross browser way of knowing (event) when a browser repaint has finished. So yeah, though it seems like a hack, its used in quite a few places.

Comment: Yeah, I know it works like a process-yeld in cooperative multitasking.   It makes sense: since angular presumably doesn't yeld its execution stack until it finishes, it does all the work before the focus() call is ready to go. Thank you.

Comment: Be careful when you use the ngAnimate module. This solution won't work anymore because the input won't become instantly visible. Just a hint.

Comment: More of a general note, but depending on the circumstances, there may be cases where it is necessary to set the timeout value to something larger than 0, e.g., 100.