# Tab Through Hidden Inputs in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, input, hidden

I'm looking for a way in angular to tab through hidden inputs. So I have multiple input forms but when not on focus I want them to just display the text. I'm looking for the ability to once I've selected an input to tab through the other inputs even though they are currently hidden.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You cannot focus hidden elements. Just style them differently when not focused on, instead of hiding them. That, or when pressing "tab", change the type from "hidden" to "text" and _then_ trigger the focus event.

Comment: To expand on @jperezov's comment, from the jQuery documentation on .focus(): Attempting to set focus to a hidden element causes an error in Internet Explorer. Take care to only use .focus() on elements that are visible. To run an element's focus event handlers without setting focus to the element, use .triggerHandler( "focus" ) instead of .focus().

Comment: I don't if visibility : hidden have same behavior as display:none in current case, you can check it, other way is to set width : 0, it will work, but it can still have some focus effect.

Comment: Do you mean "previously-hidden inputs"? i.e. As you tab through the form, you want your action to (a) change the text field into an input field, and (b) set the focus on that input field?

Comment: @VishalBardoloi Yes. I want to be able to display the information nicely in a table but I want a user to be able to click on cell and be able to start tabbing through to enter information.

Comment: @AtownWatas ah, you're looking for an inline editor then. I've done that in Angular before using directives - answer coming shortly with code snippets.

Comment: Also look at this SO for another implementation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15613773/angularjs-setting-focus-on-a-previously-hidden-input-element-inside-a-directive

Answer (score 0):

Use Angular directives to make your inputs into inline editors. When the page loads you'll be in display mode (i.e. the display div will be shown and the editor div will be hidden), then on clicking, the mode switches to Edit mode and the visibility is reversed.

Here's a quick snippet of what a DatePicker control would look like when wrapped in such a directive. Using Angular 1 and Bootstrap 3 (follows [John Papa's Angular Style Guide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide)):

HTML Template (inlineDatePicker.html):

```
<div class="inline-edit">
    <div ng-if="!vm.inEditMode" data-ng-click="vm.enableEditMode()">
        <input type="hidden" data-ng-model="vm.dateModel" data-ng-required="vm.dateRequired" /><span>{{vm.dateModel}}</span> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
    </div>
    <div ng-if="vm.inEditMode">
        <div class="well well-sm" style="position: absolute; z-index: 10">
            <datepicker data-ng-model="vm.dateModel" data-show-weeks="false"></datepicker>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-info" ng-click="vm.today()">Today</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" ng-click="vm.cancel()">Cancel</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the underlying directive (inlineDatePicker.directive.js):

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('myApp.inlineEdit')
    .directive('inlineDatePicker', inlineDatePicker);

    function inlineDatePicker() {
        'use strict';
        inlineDatePickerController.$inject = ['$scope', '$timeout'];

        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            replace: true,
            transclude: false,
            templateUrl: '/App/inlineEdit/date/inlineDatePicker.html',
            scope: {
                dateModel: '=',
                dateRequired: '@',
                dateChanged: '&'
            },
            controller: inlineDatePickerController,
            controllerAs: 'vm',
        };

        function inlineDatePickerController($scope, $timeout) {
            /* jshint validthis:true */
            var vm = this;
            vm.inEditMode = false;
            vm.dateModel = $scope.dateModel;
            vm.dateRequired = $scope.$eval($scope.dateRequired);
            vm.enableEditMode = enableEditMode;
            vm.cancel = cancel;
            vm.today = today;

            function enableEditMode() {
                vm.inEditMode = true;
            }

            function cancel() {
                vm.inEditMode = false;
            }

            function today() {
                vm.dateModel = new Date();
            }

            $scope.$watch('vm.dateModel', function (curr, orig) {
                $scope.dateModel = vm.dateModel;
                if (curr != orig && vm.inEditMode) {
                    $timeout($scope.dateChanged, 0);
                }
                vm.inEditMode = false;
            });

            $scope.$watch('dateModel', function () {
                vm.dateModel = $scope.dateModel;
            });
        }        
    }
})();
```